# Recursive Structure Modeling in Mongo Document

Tags: mongodb, recursion

I'm trying to define an appropriate document structure using Mongo.  My data represents an "event" which itself can be made up of N level of nested events each with a time associated with it:

```js
{
 eventName: "TopEvent",
 time: "1000",
 eventType: "Type1",
 events:[{
  eventName: "EventA1",
  time: "200",
  eventType: "Type2",
  event: [], /* no child events */
 },{
  eventName: "EventB1",
  time: "800",
  eventType: "Type2",
  event: [
  {
    eventName: "EventB2",
    time: "500",
    eventType: "Type2",
    event: [], /* no child events */
   },{
    eventName: "EventB3",
    time: "300",
    eventType: "Type2",
    event: [], /* no child events */
   },
  ],
 },

 ]
```

Is this an appropriate way to model this information in Mongo such that I can find data (at any level of the recursion) by eventName, eventType and time?